# mod_rewrite for pretty urls and special characters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, urlencode

I am using the following code to rediect uri requests to my index.php file with GET vars

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?parent=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/)?$ index.php?parent=$1&child=$2 [L]
```

so the url

```
mysite.com/category/article  // resolves to 
$_GET['parent'] = category
$_GET['child'] = article
```

I encode the URLs for the nav so that

```
mysite.com/dates-&-events/ becomes mysite.com/dates-%26-events/
```

however this breaks the mod_rewrite resolving to

```
$_GET['parent'] = dates-
```

breaking the string prematurely.
How do I change my regex to include encoded reserved characters in the group?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [`B` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b):

> The [B] flag instructs RewriteRule to escape non-alphanumeric characters before applying the transformation.
>
> mod_rewrite has to unescape URLs before mapping them, so backreferences will be unescaped at the time they are applied. Using the B flag, non-alphanumeric characters in backreferences will be escaped.